# Rails/Devise: XHR returns 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app that uses Devise for authentication. I authenticate through the usual Rails views, and most of the app is done with the usual Rails ActionView pages.

One page of my app includes a React app that requests data via XHR with the isomorphic-fetch library. I've been developing it in Safari, which works fine, but in Chrome or Firefox I get HTTP 401 messages when I try an XHR get.

It appears that the difference is that on Safari I am getting a response header of 'Set-Cookie' that sets a session cookie, and in Chrome I'm not.

Here's what I've tried:
* Adding `X-CSRF-Token` to my AJAX fetch requests
* Setting `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr` to true and setting `config.navigational_format = [:html, :json]`

It's a new Rails 5 app. I have a similar Rails 4 app where the XHRs work fine. How do I make my XHRs work here?

Comment: Did you check the submitted headers for the different browsers? Maybe there is something missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work. I checked my previous app, which used jQuery for the AJAX calls. When I replaced `fetch` with `jquery-ujs`, it worked! I saw my problem was that it had not been sending the session cookie with the request. I researched how to do this with `isomorphic-fetch`, and found the [github/fetch](https://github.github.io/fetch/#Headers) documentation. When I structure my request like this, it works:

```
fetch('/my_resource.json?param=someparam', {
  'credentials': 'same-origin'
})
```

Gotta send the cookies.